# SQL Server FREETEXTTABLE minimum length

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, freetexttable

I'm getting no results when using a FREETEXTTABLE query when my search string is only 3 characters in length (when its 4 it returns results).
Below is the code I'm running when it returns results, but if I change my search term to 'gol' it returns no results.

```
DECLARE  @strSearchWords varchar(500)   = 'golf'
SELECT sku, title
FROM products AS p INNER JOIN
    FREETEXTTABLE(products, title, @strSearchWords) AS search_table
    ON p.product_id = search_table.[KEY]
ORDER BY 
    search_table.RANK DESC
```

I'm sure its most likely a database setting but I've not been able to find anything referencing it. or is it just too broad a search for it to find any matches?

Comment: Another thought that just came to mind is that it is seeing it as a 'noise' word and so ignoring it

Comment: Do you see it if you run select * from sys.fulltext_system_stopwords?

Comment: I have tried that and its not in there, so there goes that thought!